# Alpine Linux apk continues to install despite pre-install failure

Tags: alpine-linux, apk-tools

The documentation for the Alpine package says the following of the pre-install script:

`Note the exit 0 at the end. If the script exits with failure (if the user already exist), the package will not be installed and apk add will exit with failure.`

However, this isn't the case for me, when the pre-install script returns `1` apk *does* print the error `pre-install: script exited with error 1`, and also continues to install the package as well as run all the other install scripts (post-install) as if nothing happened.

Is there any way for me to actually abort the installation should the pre-install fail?

Upon further investigation I saw this while installing an official package:

```
(1/1) Installing dnsmasq (2.80-r3)
Executing dnsmasq-2.80-r3.pre-install
Executing busybox-1.30.1-r3.trigger
```

So the *pre*-install actually executes *after* the install (☉_☉)

Comment: What Alpine version? Could you give more details on the specific package(s) with this issue? Or is it a home-brewed package?

Comment: @valiano It's a homebrewed package, that's why I'm trying to figure out how pre-install scripts work. Oh and it's Alpine 3.10